# Set Method And Get Method Of A Fixed Size Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a bit mixed up on how to apply the 'sets' and 'gets' methods for a fixed array.  Here is some of my work in Netbeans:

```
//creating 5 fixed arrays of size 10
private String [] itemnames = new String [10];
private String [] itemcodes = new String [10];
private String [] category = new String [10];
private String [] quantity = new String [10];
private Double [] sellingprice = new Double [10];



//initialising each array to null in the class constructor

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   itemnames[i] = "";
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   itemcodes[i] = "";
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   category[i] = "";
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   quantity[i] = "";
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   (Double.parseDouble(sellingprice[i])) = 0;
}
```

Now, i'm stuck in the set method and the get method of each array.  Any help please?

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "the set method and the get method of each array"? It's entirely unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If you pass in the index as well as the value, then you would set the element in that position to the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make set and get methods according to what you want to do (or later be able to do) with the arrays.

If you want to be able to retrieve an array into another class, you could make a get method like this:

```
public String[] getItems()
{
   return itemnames;
}
```

If on the other hand you only want other classes to get the specific items in your arrays, one method might look like this:

```
public String getItemMatchingCode(String code)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < ARR_LENGTH; i++)
   {
       if(code.equals(itemcodes[i]) return itemnames[i];
   }
}
```

Or you might want to set and get the different values based on ideces:

```
public String getItemnameAt(int i)
{
   return itemnames[i];
}

public void setItemnameAt(int i, String newItemname)
{
   itemnames[i] = newItemname;
}
```

Sidenotes:
You are not "//initialising each array to null in the class constructor", they are that by default. What you are doing is filling them with empty strings, which in most cases is unnecessary.

When iterating through the arrays and filling them with values you can do them all in one loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   itemnames[i] = "";
   itemcodes[i] = "";
   category[i] = "";
}
```

Edit:
Also consider using a constant when declaring the size of the arrays, like so:

```
private static final int ARR_SIZE = 10;
private String[] array = new String[ARR_SIZE];
```